# Resource IDs in arb files must Start with capital ?(flutter localization: i18n and l10n support)

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, flutter-intl

I have a flutter project, and updated it to nullsafety just now. And I found that intl_translation plugin are not support for nullsafety. So I remove it and want to use the intl comes with the framwork of flutter.

According to the [official documents](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization), I add 2 lines: `intl: ^0.17.0 #`  , `generate: true` and new a file named `l10n.yaml` .

l10n.yaml 's content as follow:

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: intl_en.arb
output-localization-file: lib/generated/intl/l10n.dart
```

Then my file tree as follow:

```
lib
├── data
│   ├── ......
├── generated
│   ├── intl
│   │   ├── messages_all.dart
│   │   ├── messages_en.dart
│   │   └── messages_zh.dart
│   └── l10n.dart
├── l10n
│   ├── intl_en.arb
│   └── intl_zh.arb
├── ......
├── ......
├── ui
│   ├── ......
└── utilities.dart
```

Then I `flutter run` my project. The ERRORS show that

```
Invalid ARB resource name "UPCredit" in LocalFile: '.../lib/l10n/intl_en.arb'.
Resources names must be valid Dart method names: they have to be camel case, cannot start with a number or underscore, and cannot contain non-alphanumeric characters.
Generating synthetic localizations package has failed.
```

The error position is in my `intl_en.arb` as follows:

```
"UPxxt": "Uxxx Cxxxit",
"UPxit": "Unxxx Dxxxt",
"UPSxit": "Uxxx Sxxxed xxxit",
```

**MY PROBLEM**:
NoBody talk me not to do like this(Maybe I can not find something about it). Can anybody help me about how to solve it? Something about document(how to find this?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the means exactly `camelCase` this kind of naming convention to be used hence you'll need to stick with `upCredit` instead of `UpCredit`.

Comment: Actually, I have tried to use ```camelCase```. It does not work. After ```flutter run ```, there shows that ```Generating synthetic localizations package has failed.```

Comment: make required changes in `pubspec.yaml` file as in it is over [here](https://github.com/CyberWake/talawa/blob/animations/pubspec.yaml) and the run `pub get`

Comment: I **SOLVED** this problem by upCredit. Thanks!